# Angular2 TypeError: val.slice is not a function. Issue with Primeng datatable & nested data

Tags: angular

I am trying to use primeng dataTable. In which I am loading nested JSON in "jsonArray" given below:

```html
{
  "person_name": "Gaurav",
  "personal_details":[{
    "last_name":"patel",
    "age":24
  }],
  "technical_details":[{
    "roll_no":1,
    "branch":"IT"
  }]
}
```

```js
//app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  jsonArray: any[]=[];
  constructor(public AppSVC: AppService) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    this.AppSVC.getAppontmentJson().subscribe(res => {
      if (!res.error_status) {
        this.jsonArray = res;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
//app.component.html
<p-dataTable [value]="jsonArray" reorderableColumns="true">
  <p-column header="Last Name" field="personal_details.last_name"></p-column>
  <p-column header="Age" field="personal_details.last_name"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

But when I run the code, it shows an error:

**ERROR TypeError: val.slice is not a function**

And I am new to angular 2

Comment: I haven't used val.slice anywhere

Comment: Try to change `jsonArray: any[]=[];` to `jsonArray: any = {};`

Comment: What is the exact output you got from the getAppontmentJson() subscription? You have given an object in the very first of your description but you declared  jsonArray as an array.
You always need to set a collection in the `[value]` properties of **p-datatable**

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the data is not formatted correctly . You need to assign an array to the data table.

```
[{
  "person_name": "Gaurav",
  "personal_details":{
    "last_name":"patel",
    "age":24
  },
  "technical_details":{
    "roll_no":1,
    "branch":"IT"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Yes, Error is gone! but it isn't showing the values from the JSON

Comment: did you ad the DataTable and Column directives to the componen

Comment: can you create a plunker

Comment: `personal_details` and `technical_details` should be JSON object not List.